# yii URL user freindly

Tags: php, url, yii

I am using $_GET instead of $_POST, but I dont like the result or model name to appear at URL

At the View I let the form type GET not POST

```
 $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('/OperationReport'),
    'method'=>'GET',

));
```

At Controller

```
public function actionReportform() {

    $operation  = new Operation ;
    $this->render('reportform', array(
        'model' => $operation,
    ));
}


 public function actionOperationReport() {

    $this->layout = '//layouts/report';   

    $status             = CHtml::encode($_GET['Operation']['status']);
    $date1          = CHtml::encode($_GET['Operation']['reception_date']);
    $date2          = CHtml::encode($_GET['Operation']['reception_date_2']);

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->condition = "user_id =:userid";
    $criteria->params =array(':userid'=> Yii::app()->user->id) ;
    $criteria->order = 'reception_date  DESC ';

    !empty($date1)        ? $criteria->addInCondition('reception_date >', array($date1)) : "";
    !empty($date2)        ? $criteria->addInCondition('reception_date <', array($date2)) : "";  
!empty($status)       ? $criteria->addInCondition('status ', array($status)) : "";
$result = Operation::model()->findAll($criteria);

    if ($result == null) {
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'There is no result for your selection .');
    } else {   
        $this->render('OperationReport', array( 
                'operations'=>$result , 
                'reception_date'=>$date1,
                'reception_date_2'=>$date2,
                'status'=>$status,

        ));
    }
}
```

Here is the result link that I dont want it totaly
http://localhost:85/myapplication/operation/OperationReport?Operation[reception_date]=2014-11-01&Operation[reception_date_2]=2015-01-14&Operation[status]=1

I would like the link shoud be like this
http://localhost:85/myapplication/operation/OperationReport/reception_date/2014-11-01/reception_date_2/2015-01-14/status/1

I did this a while ago, but I forgot if it was with GET or POST

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is POST method. GET method is not good solution the for form with multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can look to routing and urlManager, but do this if you really need to and you're not dealing with flexible parameters cause managing urls this way can become very tideous. Keep in mind this effect your site globally.
To rewrite specific urls you can add this line to your urlManager in config.php.

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'appendParams' => false,
    'showScriptName' => false, // to remove index.php from urls
    'rules' => array(
        '' => 'site/index', //optional: makes your homepage http://domain.com/
        '<controller:(operation)>/<action:(operationReport)>/reception_date/<Operation[reception_date]>/reception_date_2/<Operation[reception_date_2]>/status/<Operation[status]>' => 'operation/operationReport'
    ),
)
```

I haven't tested the rule but it should do what you need it to